# powerup in race game

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I've got a problem: i need to add a powerup to a racegame, using collision detection.
so i drawed the powerup, but the problem is: It has to be drawn after every 5 rounds and it needs to be placed ramdomly on the track.

Someone with any good advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it need to be a true random, or merely appear random to the user?

If it's the latter, I would recommend flagging powerup spots (perhaps as coordinates on the map) instead of randomly placing one *anywhere* on the map.  It will significantly reduce the complexity of what you're trying to write.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a bit vague. So here is my best shot at an answer.

You would want to use the c# Random class, [here are the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random_members%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

For a simple game, using rectangular collision should be all you need (I assume thats what you are using) - If you want to randomly generate the power-up position, you will want to create a new Vector2 (the powerups position) with the random generator.

You can use the Next function, to pass in a low, and high variable - which you would need to configure the the bounds you wish the powerup to appear.

My advice as a game designer on the other hand, tells me that randomly located power-ups aren't always the go. It makes it harder to control the games flow and balance, and can very easily result in a flawed final product.

So my advice is a hard coded set of possible weapon spawn points - using a random generator to pick one to place.

Comment: Bounding-circle collision detection would be even easier than rectangular.